# Victory Chart Custom Legend in react

Tags: reactjs, charts, legend

I want to change icon like

[image]

but in documentation can't find custom legend

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Victory Chart Legend Custom Icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51711503/victory-chart-legend-custom-icon)